# Displaying method to run after sometime using delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, delayed-job

I am new to ruby and i have a messaging application where whenever a user send a message after sometime it should display an automated message after a span of 1 minute
I have used delayed job gem and created a perform method inside mailing_job.rb which is in my app/job folder
Now when my code executes it works properly but it does not wait for the  specified delayed time but instead executes on that time itself . I have the same method created in my controller too and the delayed method syntax is using the controller method and not the perform method from my mailin_job.rb
Here is the snippet for my message controller

```
def reply
    @message = MessageThread.new(message_params)
    @user2 = get_user(params[:id])
    save_message

    Mailing_Job.set(wait: 1.minute).perform_later()

    render 'material_admin/home.html.erb'
end
```

In my app/job/mailing_job.rb file

```
class Mailing_Job < ActiveJob::Base
queue_as :default

 def perform()

    @auto_message = Setting.all[0]
    @body = @auto_message.body

end
end
```

config/application.rb file

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

chat_user_message view

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
```

```
<div class='right-message'>
  <div class='margin-bottom'>
    <span class='yellow'><%= message.body %></span>
  </div>
  <small>
    <%= message.created_at.strftime(" %I:%M %p") %>
  </small>
  <div>
    <small>
      <%= @body %>
    </small> </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class='left-message'>
  <div class='margin-bottom'>
    <span class='grey'><%= message.body %></span>
  </div>
  <small>
    <%= message.created_at.strftime(" %I:%M %p")%>
  </small>
</div>
```

Can anyone please explain me what i am doing wrong, Thanks in advance

Comment: "display an automated message after a span of 1 minute" you mean send an email?

Comment: no it displays ont he same chat box in a small div its a real time chat application, so everytime a user sends a message i want it to display an automated message like Message Sent after one minute displaying just below to the message which he sent @phoet

Comment: I really don't get. Why do you pass a result of running a controller method `automated_message` to somewhere? It will obviously run, 'cause you call it `perform_later(automated_message)`  calls it and sends a result as an attribute to `perform_later`.        Do you really need any parameter to your `perform` method? It seems like you do not use it.

Comment: Also: do you really want to duplicate this code? Notice, that in your `perform` method you set instance variables `@auto_message` and `body` not for your controller, but for your `Mailing_Job` class object. You probably won't be able to use them. (Also it have to be `MailingJob`, with no `_`)

Comment: Yes i got that part understood and i changed my parameters, i checked my logs and the mailin_job is running in the background i want the the @body varariable to display in my view after the mailing_job is performed how should i do that?

Comment: i have updated my code accordingly i want that the variable @body created in mailing_job should display in my view after the mailing_job get performed is there a way ican access that variable in my view?

Comment: @MohammedSayer unfotunately you have completely misunderstood the usage of delayed-job. its purpose is to handle asynchronous actions such as sending emails. if you want to do something in the view, use ajax requests or action cable or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delayed_job runs in a separate process from your main Rails app and isn't able to create any part of the view. Also, once the "reply" action renders, your server drops the connection to the client and has no way to contact it later when the job executes unless you implement something like Web Sockets.

A simpler option might be add some Javascript to the view that checks another method on the server (e.g. every 15 seconds) to see if the job has completed. It could notify the user when it detects that the job has completed.